# ExtJS 3.4: How to add a custom renderer dynamically to a PropertyGrid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I need to display an image in a PropertyGrid. This is usually achieved using the customRenderers config, explicitly overriding the rendered for a specific field:

```
grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
    customRenderers: {
        "picture": function(v)
        {
            return "<img src=\"" + feature.attributes["picture"] + "\" />";
        }
    }
});
```

But in my case the field on which to apply the custom rendering function is only known at run-time (I have to search for a string like "http:"). But adding the custom renderer dynamically at that time does no seem to work.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Here is how the dynamic property is found:

```
for (var key in feature.attributes)
{   
    value = feature.attributes[key];
    if ((value != null) && (value.substring(0, 4) == "http"))   
        grid.customRenderers[key] = Function("v", "return \"<img src=\\\"" + value + "\\\" />\";"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a great deal of different strategies I finally got to something that functions:

```
grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid();
for (var key in feature.attributes)
{   
    value = feature.attributes[key];
    if ((value != null) && (value.substring(0, 4) == "http"))   
        grid.customRenderers[key] = Function("v", "return \"<img src=\\\"" + value + "\\\" />\";"); 
}
```

The `feature.attributes` is a dictionary containing the data to be displayed; a cycle iterates through each of its keys, searching for the fields that might contain image URLs.

There were two key elements that brought me to this solution:

- Understanding that `customRenderers` can be used itself as a dictionary, thus dispensing the hard-coding of fields names.
- The usage of `Function` as a means to encode the exact value to be rendered, this way avoiding any scope issues.

Comment: Your answer is *exactly* what I wrote... Except you are still confused about what you are doing. `Function("v", "return ...")` is exactly like writing `function(v){return ...}` and has nothing to do with scope issues. And `customRenderers` is indeed a property of the component that can be affected after it is created... Just like my example does if you bother reading it... (sigh)

Answer (score 0):

Even though customRenderers is a config property, it is still accessible after the component is created. You can dynamically add them after the grid is created.

Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wxx3M/1/

**HTML**:

```
<p id="button-container"></p>
<div id="prop-grid"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var propsGrid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
        renderTo: 'prop-grid',
        width: 300,
        autoHeight: true,
        propertyNames: {
            tested: 'QA',
            borderWidth: 'Border Width'
        },
        source: {
            '(name)': 'Properties Grid',
            grouping: false,
            autoFitColumns: true,
            productionQuality: false,
            created: new Date(Date.parse('10/15/2006')),
            tested: false,
            version: 0.01,
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        viewConfig : {
            forceFit: true,
            scrollOffset: 2 // the grid will never have scrollbars
        }
    });

    // simulate updating the grid data via a button click
    new Ext.Button({
        renderTo: 'button-container',
        text: 'Update custom renderer',
        handler: function(){
            var targetProp = null;
            for (var key in feature.attributes)
            {   
                value = feature.attributes[key];
                if ((value != null) && (value.substring(0, 4) == "http"))
                    targetProp = key;   
            }
            propsGrid.customRenderers[targetProp] = function(v){
                return v ? 'XXX' : '';
            }
            propsGrid.getView().refresh();
        }
    });
});
```

Initially there is no custom renderers. If you click the button, a new dynamic custom renderer is added.

Comment: The field on which to apply the custom renderer in only known at run-time, thus your proposal will not do it. Thanks for answering in any case.

Comment: Well so is my answer! The custom renderer is only added when you click the button.

Comment: This solution only functions if you know a priori the field on which to apply the custom renderer. I clearly stated in the question that this is not the case.

Comment: Your question does not state how your property is found dynamically except for some ambiguous comment about searching for a string. In my button handler, you are able to do that search and then apply it in the next line `propsGrid.customRenderers[your_field] = function(v){`

Comment: I simplified my answer because I think you didn't realize that in a json object, `a.b` is equivalent to `a['b']`...

Comment: To everyone else: I just tried this proposal and it is still not functional. The user seems to think that `Function()` is equivalent `= function(c)` but it is not.

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle with my code just to prove that it *is* working with the exact code... even though I really don't know why I'm losing so much time trying to explain something to you. Cya.